# Datetime column in React Table

Tags: reactjs

I have data which are bind in react-table v6. Also with custom values. I want to convert date field in react-table as well as wants to format data which are added into it. Here is my react table format:

```
 <ReactTable 
          getTdProps={defaultGetTdPropsBuilder(
            setShouldRedirect,
            setRedirectTo,
            baseURL
          )}
          filterable
          data={items}
          columns={[{
              Header: "ID",
              accessor: "id",
            }, {
              Header: "Est. Closing Date",
              accessor:  "est_closing_date",
            },{
              Header: "Est. Closing Date",
              accessor: "est_completion_date", 
            },{
              Header: "Next Action",
              accessor: "next_action", 
            },{
              Header: "Invoice Amount",
              accessor: "invoice_amount",
            }, 

          ]}
        />
```

Data which are shown in table is :[image]

I want Next Action should be "`Follow Up Email`" in table column of `Next Action`. Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cell Property like
Cell: props => {customFormatFunction(props.value)} // Custom cell

```
{
  Header: "Est. Closing Date",
  accessor:  "est_closing_date",
  Cell: props => {moment(props.value).format('dd/MM/yyyy')} // Add moment js or use js Date formatting
},
```

Reference:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6

Comment: Also I want to change string format for follow up email as I explained.

Comment: @DaminiSuthar use can format follow up email like  {(props.value).replace(" ","_")}

Comment: Yes but I want that in capitalized format

Comment: @DaminiSuthar use toUpperCase() to Capitalize   {(props.value).replace(" ","_").toUpperCase()}

Answer (score 1):

use this syntax of cell property: props => {customFormatFunction(props.value)}

```
 {
 Header: "Est. Closing Date",
 accessor:  "est_closing_date",
 Cell: props => {moment(props.value).format('dd/MM/yyyy')} 
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
      Header: 'Date',
      accessor: (d) => {
        return moment(d.createdAt)
          .format("DD-MMM-YYYY")
      }
    },
```

### return   '18-may-2023'